# Torsion-free abelian groups of finite rank and a subgroup of finite index (Fuchs' problem) - self study

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

I'm trying to solve the following exercise (Fuchs, "Infinite Abelian Groups", Vol. $2$, pp. $153$, Ex.$5$):

> Let $A$ be a torsion-free abelian group of finite rank.
>   If $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $A$ into itself, then $\phi A$ is of finite index in $A$.
>   [Hint: if $F$ is a free subgroup of $A$ of the same rank as $A$, then $F\cap \phi F$ is of finite index in $F$; apply Ex. $4$ to $\phi A / (F\cap \phi F)\le A/(F\cap \phi F)$, noting that $A/F\cong \phi A/\phi F$.]

In order to get some intuition, I've considered the finitely generated free group $F=\oplus_{i=1}^n\langle x_i\rangle\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}$.
If $\phi$ is a monomorphism of A into intself, then $F\cap \phi F\cong\oplus_{i=1}^m \mathbb{Z}$ for some $m\le n$ since every subgroup of a free group is again free.
But now $F/(F\cap\phi F)\cong\mathbb{Z}^n/\mathbb{Z}^m\cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-m}$, which doesn't have finite index if $m < n$.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First, note that $F\cap\phi F$ is not **equal** to a sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, it is **isomorphic** to such a sum (the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ sending $1$ to $2$ has image isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but not equal to $\mathbb{Z}$). Second: what you are noting is that the intersection cannot by free of rank less than $n$.

Comment: Tangential to your question, but I would warn you that referring to an "isomorphism of $A$ into itself" is very old-fashioned and is not standard terminology anymore (it is now nearly universal that isomorphisms must be surjective).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I've got your suggestion, but I still don't see how to prove the statement :-(

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks :-)

Comment: If $F\cap\phi F$ were of infinite index, then you would be able to take a basis for $F$, and add an element $x$ with $\langle x\rangle\cap\phi F$ trivial, which would give you a subgroup of $F$ of rank strictly larger than that of $F$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your explanations! Now I'll try to solve the whole problem. If I have some problems, I'll write down them! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The hint refers to Ex.4: why don't you include Ex.4 since it's the key to the problem?